# To show that H,K are sub-groups of G (U36)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, normal-subgroups, coprime

Let $G\:=U_{36}$ and

$$H=\left\{\left[x\right]\in U_{36}\::\:x\equiv 1\pmod{4}\right\},$$
$$K=\left\{\left[y\right]\in U_{36}\::\:y\equiv 1\pmod{9}\right\}.$$

I need to show that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$.

First of all, lets write them explicitly for clearly view, what we to show finally, so: 
$$G=\left\{\left[1\right],\left[5\right],\left[7\right],\left[11\right],\left[13\right],\left[17\right],\left[19\right],\left[23\right],\left[25\right],\left[29\right],\left[31\right],\left[33\right],\left[35\right]\right\},$$
$$H=\left\{\left[1\right],\left[5\right],\left[13\right],\left[17\right],\left[25\right],\left[29\right],\left[33\right]\right\},$$
$$K=\left\{\left[1\right],\left[19\right]\right\}.$$

Let's start from $H$. It is clearly a subset, so I'll check all the conditions for a group, and if it's a group and sub-set, it is a subgroup of $G$:

Clearly, it isn't empty and $G$ is a group, therefore all that elements are assosiative, because they from the $G$ group.

I claim that $[1]$ is the identity element, because for each $x\in H$ we have $x\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, so
$$x\cdot 1\equiv 1\cdot x\equiv x\pmod{4}.$$

***Not correct from here:***

And now I want to show that for each $x\in H$ there exists $x^{-1}\in H$ such that $xx^{-1}=\left[1\right]$.

But from modularic arithmetic rules, for each $x_1,x_2\in H$ we have $x_1\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $x_2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, so
$$x_1\cdot x_2\equiv 1\cdot 1\equiv 1\pmod{4}.$$

So as I understand each elements in $H$ is the opposite of each other. But that makes me think that every element is either the identity element for each other, because: 
$$17\cdot 29\equiv 17\equiv 1\pmod{4}.$$

Am I just confused in this or it is a special characteristics of modulo $1$? 
Otherwise, maybe I don't understand how do we define here the identity element and the inverse, because the operator here is modulo, but the identity element, I think about him as multiply, either the inverse.

***Until here***

Otherwise, maybe $1$ is the identity element, but using Euclid algorithm to find the opposite in this cases, randomly I found that for $[5]$ the opposite is $[-7]$, what modulo 36 means $[29]$ ,for [13] it is $[-11]$, Therefore $[25]$ and $[17]$ is the opposite of himself. 
So what about $[1]$, does it have opposite?

And is it true for from modularic arithmetic rules, that I always have opposites in such examples of U, or I have to check for each element in hand mode?

For example in K, as I understand now, the opposite of $19$ is itself, the identity element is $1$ (why ? can some one define for me identity in modulo explicitly and explain it to me?), associativity from $G$, and closure also from modularic arithmetic rule, because multiply of $2$ elements modulo, is an element is modulo, right?

Correct me whenever I didn't explain good enough or missed something please.

Comment: Associativity is not a property of elements of a (sub)set, it is a property of a binary relation (on a set).

And by showing that $x_1x_2\equiv1\pmod4$ whenever $x_1\equiv1\pmod4$ and $x_2\equiv1\pmod4$, you have shown that the subset $H$ is closed under the group operation on $G$. You have not shown that each element is its own inverse, or that each element is the identity. This is in fact not true.

Comment: I ment that it inherited from G, which isnt a simple set, but a Group. Yes, about the second thing I agree, I corrected myself next, but I didnt erased the first mistake, because i wanted to leave behind my confusion, so the reader could see it and understand me clearly.

Comment: So, eventually, how do I show clearly identity element and opposite in general case, because in that example 36 is a pretty small number, and the amount of elemnts in both sub-groups is not big, but do I show that for each elements there is an opposite? 
I do know how to find them manualy by Euclid's algorithm (g.c.d), but I cant use it for 100 elements for example.

Comment: See the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you mean $G$ is a cyclic group of order $36$. By the looks of it you are considering $\Bbb{Z}/36\Bbb{Z}$. Do note that $33$ is not coprime to $36$, so $[33]\notin G$.

To check that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ we need to check three conditions:

1. That $H$ is a non-empty subset of $G$.
2. That $H$ is closed under the group operation on $G$.
3. That for every $h\in H$ we have $h^{-1}\in H$.

The first part is obvious. The second part you have already verified: If $h_1,h_2\in H$ then 
$$h_1\equiv1\pmod4\qquad\text{ and }\qquad h_2\equiv1\pmod4,$$
 from which it follows that $h_1h_2\equiv1\pmod4$ and therefore $h_1h_2\in H$.

The third condition can be more difficult. In this case it suffices to check that
$$[5]\cdot[29]=[1],\qquad[13]\cdot[25]=[1],\qquad [17]\cdot[17]=[1],$$
and of course $[1]\cdot[1]=[1]$. It follows that $H$ is a group under the group operation on $G$ (restricted to $H$), which means $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

You can do the same for $K$.

---

Note that you do not need to check the third condition if your (candidate) subgroup is *finite*. If a finite subset $H$ of a group $G$ is closed under the group operation on $G$, then for every $h\in H$ there exist distinct positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $h^m=h^n$. Without loss of generality $m>n$, and we find
$$h^{m-n}=h^m\cdot h^{-n}=h^n\cdot h^{-n}=e,$$
where $e$ denotes the identity element. Then $h^{m-n-1}=h^{-1}$, which shows that $h^{-1}\in H$ because $H$ is closed under the group operation.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. But what should we do with third conditon, if we had much greater order of G and of H? 
Do we need manually to check each element for it's oppsite (I use Euclid's algorithm of g.c.d as I mentioned) ? 
Isnt there any rule or something ?

Comment: The last paragraph explains why the third condition does not need to be checked if $H$ is finite. If some part of this is unclear, I'll be glad to clarify it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didnt noticed )) And why this sentence is correct, about the existence of such m and n ?

Comment: Because $H$ is closed under the group operation we have $h^2=h\cdot h\in H$, and by induction $h^{n+1}=h^n\cdot h\in H$ for all $n>0$. The infinite sequence $h^1,h^2,h^3,\ldots$ is then in $H$, which is finite, so certainly some element of $H$ must occur more than once. This is why we must have $h^m=h^n$ for some distinct $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Excellent! And just for the good order, dont you need to show before the existence of the opposite, an existence of an identity element, otherwise what is h*opp_h ?

Comment: Or maybe if we showed an oposite, then by definition h*opp_h = e that relates to H. It should be that, I guess.

Comment: Exactly; conditions 2 and 3 together imply that $e\in H$.

Comment: I want to use this for another exercise, but I don't understand now your final conclusion from this step: 
We have: $h^{m-n}=e$ now we multiple each side by $h^{-1}$ as I understand and conclude that it is in H. Why ? 

In this step $h^{-1}$ we dont know if it in H, and by mutplying $h^{m-n}$ and this creatue $h^{-1}$, why we conclude that it is in H?

I mean, you say because of closure, but we don't know where is $h^{-1}$, so closure doesn't work for him and $h^{m-n}$, why you conclude that from closure the multiply of them is in H ?

I mean, I dont see why $h^{m-n}*h^{-1}\in $H$?

Comment: I don't get $h^{m-n-1}$ from the multiplication $h^{m-n}\cdot h^{-1}$. I get $h^{m-n-1}$ by multiplying $h\cdot h\cdots h$ precisely $m-n-1$ times. This is in $H$ because it is closed under multiplication and $h\in H$, and $m-n-1$ is a nonnegative integer.